# How to return result from Task<HttpResponseMessage>, to take the benefit of Async HttpClient call?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library, dotnet-httpclient

**Can I write code (1st) like bellow**

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(int id)
{
 return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model)));

}
```

**Can I write code (2nd) like bellow**

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Put(int id, string value)
{
   return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK));

}
```

I want call above described **Put** method using  `Httpclient.PutAsJsonAsync()`. in .Net 4.0 ?

Or any better way to do that ? So I can take the benefit of Async call ?

Comment: @Wouter de Kort: Ref. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910677/how-to-call-put-method-from-web-api-using-httpclient]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If none of the operations in your code are asynchronous (or blocking), then it does not make sense to have an asynchronous operation. In the two examples you have, the operation just returns a response, so you don't need to use a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` response, using the `HttpResponseMessage` is just fine.

So, more direct to your question, yes, you can write code like that, but it's more complicated than necessary, will cause a needless context switch (to create the new task), and is overall less performant. You can do it, but you shouldn't.

Comment: So you mean to if I use any HttpClient call withing a Web Api then only I use `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` as a return type ?

Comment: If you want to make asynchronous calls within the Web API, you should 1) not block on that call (e.g., by calling `.Result`) and 2) declare that your operation itself is asynchronous by marking its return type as `Task<T>`.

Comment: If within a Web API I have to returns a simple response (HttpStatusCode) & `Httpclient.PutAsJsonAsync()` call based on condition then the what return type should be use `Task<T>` or normal `HttpResponse`